# CSS files issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for the first, I added my html files in the views folder & css,jss, images in the assets folder.

Now my css etc not appearing in the layout, kindly let me know how to include/urls?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: `<link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/stylesheet.css">`

Answer (score 2):

```
go to -> your_project->application->config->config.php
```

open `config.php`

add base path of your project

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourProject/';
```

and add asset path (img, css, js)

```
define('ASSET_PATH',$config['base_url'].'assets/');
```

make sure your all css files in assets folder like this:

```
assets->css->style.css
assets->js->style.js
```

and finally used in view

```
<link href="<?php echo ASSET_PATH; ?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your css folder path like

example : **projectfolder/assets/css/style.css**

so in view file  you can use below code

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```